# Is there a C# based  web-browser?

Tags: c#, browser

Is there a C# based open-source text web-browser somewhere? A bare-bones kind of browser that does not use the web browser control. I looked in google, could'nt find one. 
edit: thanks for the answers, I was hoping for a ground-up C# based browser, something built entirely in C#. Something very basic, that can send out Get and Post requests. Or maybe built on mono? I don't understand glade and related tech; but I hear it is like WPF, so anything anywhere would be a great help.

Edit: Don't need it for business purposes. I was planning to write my own library, but if someone has already done it, then maybe I can add code. My own little open source project on the side. I mean, if it were for business, I would probably use the browser control and be done with it.

Comment: It might help if you explained why you want this.

Comment: Are you aware of the WebBrowser control?

Comment: yes, I am aware of the WebBrowser control.

Comment: I was looking for an C# library similar to the java based "Lobo".

Answer (score 4):

How bare bones do you want? Do you just want a browser that requests the page and then returns the entire response, or just the HTML as text?

You can always use [WebKit.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/).

Comment: Webkit.net is a winforms control library wrapper for webkit. Not what I was looking for.